# where can I find all keys saved in the local storage?

Tags: cookies, local-storage, session-storage, developer-tools

In chrome browser, when I access a website example.com, and I open the developer tools, I can see under the application tabs all the key:value pairs saved in local storage, but when I close my browser and reopen it, I cant see the values saved in local storage to the domain example.com unless I access again example.com. Is there a way to see all values saved in the local storage without accessing each domain?
same question for session storage and cookies.